# Matlab Images in double format

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Matlab images can be represented in double format (either grayscale or rgb). In this format the range is 0 to 1.

- When these images are represented with imshow how many colors are used? (8bit, 16bit?)
- What palete/colormap is used?
- What happens to the values above 1 and below 0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is displayed in uint8 resolution, according to RGB scheme. Values over 1 and below zero are clipped and treated as white / black.